# jquery: how to let showed div which display:none, keep showing when load to another page?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a `div` in masterpage that I set a toggle effect on it.  It's like expand folders; when you click the "folders", it will expand folders so all the sub-level folders show up.

Each sub-level folder is a hyperlink. I set the folders' `div`'s to `style="display:none"` so when you first load the page it won't show all the sub-level folders. The problem is whenever I click a sub-level folder the page reloads and the folder `div` is hidden.

How to keep it shown when it is already in shown status when directed to another page. The folder `div` is in masterpage. The `div` has `id=AppendedFolder`.

I used following code but it does not work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       if ($('#AppendedFolder').is(":visible")) 
       {
            $('#AppendedFolder').show();
        }
});
```

Comment: Are you asking how to preserve folder state when the user naviagates away from the page ?

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder: yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to save state from one page that you can use in another page, you need to save it it somewhere and then in the other pages, check that state and show the object that you wanted visible.

The classic place to save this state is in a cookie.  You would then have initialization code in your other pages that examine the value of the cookie and decide, based on the cookie value, whether to show `#AppendedFolder` or not.

Some of the other ways that you can pass state to the next page are: HTML5 local storage (only available in newer browsers) or passing a query parameter to all subsequent pages that indicates the state of this visibility.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you basically need the page, after being reloaded, to know which folders should still be expanded, correct?

In that case, it seems that you have 3 possible options:

1. If a certain URL should always have certain folders expanded, add in some JS code (or some PHP code if you can) that will expand the correct folders based on the URL.
2. Use cookies. This would allow you to maintain the same expanded folders from the previous page.
3. Any time some folders are expanded, append a parameter like "?expandedFolders=xxx" to all of the links on the page. Then, upon page load, either PHP or JS would be used to get the value of that parameter and expand the correct folders. This really wouldn't achieve anything that #2 wouldn't do, and it would definitely be more work for your script to do, and maybe more work for you to code as well.